# Git-Workflow don't know how to pull in an unmerged repo

Tags: git

I am having a problem with the git-flow.

I edited a lot of files, but I don't wan't to commit all of them so I only commited some files to my local repository.

So when I try to push my repository to the main-repo it tells me that

```
! [rejected]        
master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to <snip>
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

But I can't pull from the main-repo either because git wan'ts me to merge before

```
error: Your local changes to <snip> would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

But I don't want to commit those and I don't know how to get em back in the form they were before all the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stash your local changes using

```
git stash
```

then pull the remote changes

```
git pull
```

finally restore the changes you stashed previously

```
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to keep the `master` branch from upstream, and create your very own private branch(es) to frolic on. If some of the ideas cooking in private branches turns out a culinary masterpiece, merge (or rebase, or cherry pick) it onto `master` and push the result. Periodically synchronize your private branches by rebasing on `master`.

Read on some of the recommended git workflows [here](http://git-scm.com/)